# Pagination on API requests in Javascript/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an app that fetches data from a movie API. It returns 20 items from page 1.
How would I go about adding the ability for pagination and allowing user to click a button that increases the page number value and returns the items from that page?

Here's my API call:

```js
export const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIES_API;
export const baseURL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/';
export const language = '&language=en';
export const region = '&region=gb';
export const currentPage = 1;

export const fetchTopRatedMovies = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${baseURL}top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}${language}&page=${currentPage}${region}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('TOP RATED', data);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

I'm thinking I need to add 1 to currentPage on request however I'm unsure how to set this up.

The function is called using useEffect in React in a functional component.

```
 const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { results = [] } = apiData;

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetchTopRatedMovies().then((data) => setApiData(data));
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);
```

Comment: do not pull API_KEY from process.env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `currentPage` a param of `fetchTopRatedMovies`, so that you can pass a dynamic value from your functional component.

You should control the current viewed page in the state of your functional component like this:

```
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
```

Then you can add a button to the rendering of the functional component that in the `onClick` handler sets the new value of `currentPage` and triggers the API call. Approximately like this:

```
<MyButton onClick={() => {
    setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
    fetchTopRatedMovies(currentPage).then(data => setApiData(data));
}}>
```

I say approximately because instead of doing immediately the call to `fetchTopRatedMovies` you could leverage `useEffect` to re-run the API request on each state / prop change. Or even better, trigger the API request using `useEffect` only when there's a meaningful state / prop change.

The `fetchTopRatedMovies` method should be improved like this:

```
export const fetchTopRatedMovies = async (pageNumber) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${baseURL}top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}${language}&page=${pageNumber}${region}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('TOP RATED', data);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

This approach can be extended to all the other params of your API call.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That helps thanks. Do you recommend managing the state of the page number a separate button component or on each individual page? I'm planning on adding more pages for other api requests. Or managing the pageNumber in Context perhaps?

Comment: No matter what's your technical choice (redux / context / state) you need to keep the currentPage variable aligned with the page status. In a first implementation I'd keep it at page level, then you can move it in a redux-store or in the context.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's made by adding currentPage to the state, like

```
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage ] = useState(1);
```

So when you want to change it, via click or scroll, use setCurrentPage and in your api call it'll still use currentPage but now it'll reference the one in the state.